# What's the concept of UPLEVEL operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, uplevel

I'm not an expert in databases and I've just worked with MySQL database so far. I'm familiar with `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` statements. Also as you know, there is lots of information about them in the internet.

Recently I heard about something named `UPLEVEL` statement. I have no idea what the concept of it is, and I cannot find any good reference about it.

Well, does anybody what's that exactly?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean an UPSERT statement?

Comment: @reaanb [Nope ..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPh9o.png)

Comment: You may check [this](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=LhceBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=UPLEVEL+sql+statement&source=bl&ots=K3rZT08LXB&sig=SnZY_uqbQ3jwQxSgb3Up6VDuHMI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7jI-iqq3RAhUFKo8KHXmqCb8Q6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=UPLEVEL%20sql%20statement&f=false) reference if it helps. But I've never heard up `UPLEVEL` operator is implemented in any common databeses